# VBA Insert .bmp image to worksheet

Tags: vba, image, excel

I'm currently working on a seemingly simple task of inserting an online picture to excel using VBA. I've found examples of this online that have worked for inserting a .jpg from online, but I receive a '400' error when trying to insert a particular .bmp link shown below. Is there possible an issue with .bmp format or a possible timeout issue? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
Sub Insert_Picture()

  Dim pic As String 'file path of pic
  Dim myPicture As Picture 'embedded pic

  pic = "http://172.20.100.224/www/screenshot.bmp"

  Set myPicture = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(pic)

End Sub
```

Comment: What does error say?

Comment: The error doesn't say anything. Pops up the typical error box with 400 in it.

Comment: Hi, i've tested your code and ir works nice. are you sure that your url is ok ? it seems that is not finding the image on that url. good luck

Comment: I've tested it on other url's too with this code and it works too. Just not with this particular one. The link works outside of the VBA code, but there is a bit of loading time. Could this have something to do with not finding the image bc it takes too long?